# How can I change dynamicaly the opacity of a linegraph in D3?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

I'm using the **Dynamic Data Display** Library in WPF. 
I have my LineGraph linked to my chartplotter. I can see it in the plotter when I launch the application.

I want to know if it's possible to change the **opacity** of that linegraph while the application is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, for example, you can use a slider. When the user move the slider, it changes the opacity of the linegraph (with an event, binding...) :

```
line.LinePen.Opacity = slider.Value;
```